# How to show a message on click in angular4 when user clicks on a button

Tags: angular, forms

i am struck in designing login page, i am using angular4 formmodule,  i want to show some message on clicking sign in button but i am unable to do the same, please help me. Thank You in advance.

here is my html code,

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Hi Champ</h1>
    <form #heroForm="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"
       required>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="Password" class="form-control" id="password">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="power">Role</label>
      <br>
      <select class="form-control" id="power" required>
      <option *ngFor="let pow of powers" [value]="pow">{{pow}}</option>
      </select>
</div>

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="signin()">SignIn</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

and the code in component is totally empty, please help me,

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Hero } from '../hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-form',
  templateUrl: './hero-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hero-form.component.css']
})
export class HeroFormComponent{


   powers = ['Admin', 'Looser'];

   signin(){
   console.log("Hello");
   }

}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: no, it didnt work

Comment: @RameshRajendran , no error message too

Comment: remove `required` and try or try this in chrome browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `<form>` `<button>` **tag** and **signin** method like this:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="signin(heroForm)" #heroForm="ngForm">  
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">SignIn</button>

import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms'; 
export class HeroFormComponent{
   signin(form: NgForm){
   console.log("Hello");
   }  
}
```

Before proceeding, I strongly recommend you to read [Submit the form with ngSubmit](https://angular.io/guide/forms#submit-the-form-with-ngsubmit) in order to gain a greater understanding of Angular form concepts.

And make sure that you have included **FormsModule** in your **app.module.ts** file

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({ 
  declarations: [ ],
  imports: [ FormsModule ],
  providers: [ ]
})
```

Comment: @Anil I've edited the answer. Can you try one more time?

Comment: Can i also redirect to some url on submit button?

Comment: yeah it worked, now planning to redirect to a new page, how can i do it plz?

Comment: @Anil If you want to redirect to some other URL you can use `window.location.href = "your url";` . But, sice it is a Single Page Application why you want to redirect to an another page?

Comment: Can you please provide some resources for better understanding of this angular.

Comment: @Anil Alway try to follow the official documentation: https://angular.io/docs
 For some basic understanding : https://medium.com/@arunraj6/angular4-an-intro-711478205b5c